# Survey treatment with R language (NA values)

Tags: r, database, data-cleaning, na, survey

I'm trying to process a survey containing responses to questions. Some questions allow for multiple choices. I need to evaluate `NA` values for questions where respondents didn't answer. I'm unsure of how to organize the workflow. Could you please advise me on what to do and what steps to take to assess the actual number of truly missing responses (not artificial)? The survey contains over 500 responses and around 50 questions.

I would like also to check the correlation as it's women or men who mostly didn't answered for a particular question and so on.

I tried replacing such questions (with multiple choice) (they can take 3 or 5 columns) with a scoring system, where if at least one option is chosen for multiple-choice questions, it's assigned a value of 1 (via a loop, assigning `NA` for 0 responses). However, I struggle to replace a single question presented in multiple columns with just one column for the score, as everything gets misaligned. Moreover, there are questions where selecting an answer triggers additional questions. I'm unsure how to handle an analysis of such a survey. Also I can't just delete all the `NA` because it will affect negatively my analysis.

Example: (it's a one question but one column for each choiсe)

```
# LimeSurvey Field type: F
data[, 9] <- as.numeric(data[, 9])
attributes(data)$variable.labels[9] <- "Married"
data[, 9] <- factor(data[, 9], levels=c(1,0),labels=c("Oui", "Non sélectionné"))
names(data)[9] <- "SP01"
# LimeSurvey Field type: F
data[, 10] <- as.numeric(data[, 10])
attributes(data)$variable.labels[10] <- "Divorced"
data[, 10] <- factor(data[, 10], levels=c(1,0),labels=c("Oui", "Non sélectionné"))
names(data)[10] <- "SP02"
# LimeSurvey Field type: F
data[, 11] <- as.numeric(data[, 11])
attributes(data)$variable.labels[11] <- "Free"
data[, 11] <- factor(data[, 11], levels=c(1,0),labels=c("Oui", "Non sélectionné"))
names(data)[11] <- "SP03"
# LimeSurvey Field type: A
data[, 12] <- as.character(data[, 12])
attributes(data)$variable.labels[12] <- "Another"
names(data)[12] <- "SP0_other"


data$Family_situation <- NA
# Cycle for scoring
for (i in 1:nrow(data)) {
  Family_situation <- 0
  # Summarize
  Family_situation <- Family_situation + ifelse(data[i, "SP01"] == "Oui", 1, 0)
  Family_situation <- Family_situation + ifelse(data[i, "SP02"] == "Oui", 1, 0)
  Family_situation <- Family_situation + ifelse(data[i, "SP03"] == "Oui", 1, 0)
  if (!is.na(data[i, "SP0_other"]) && nchar(trimws(as.character(data[i, "SP0_other"]))) > 0) {
    Family_situation <- Family_situation + 1
  }
  # Create new column with score
  data[i, "Family_situation"] <- ifelse(Family_situation == 0, NA, Family_situation)
}
```

So I didn't delete three columns which are expressed in the new created column.

Comment: Please run a `dput` function on your data frame and copy the output here. this will allow us to exactly replicate your table and test the solution ourselves. make sure to remove any confidential real data, if such exist. if your table is very large, you might also consider create a subset for us with the relevant exercise you need support with.

Comment: structure(list(SP03_SQ001 = structure(c(1L, NA), levels = c("Oui", 
"Non sélectionné"), class = "factor"), SP03_SQ002 = structure(c(2L, 
NA), levels = c("Oui", "Non sélectionné"), class = "factor"), 
    SP03_SQ003 = structure(c(2L, NA), levels = c("Oui", "Non sélectionné"
    ), class = "factor"), SP03_SQ004 = structure(c(2L, NA), levels = c("Oui", 
    "Non sélectionné"), class = "factor"), SP03_SQ005 = structure(c(2L, 
    NA), levels = c("Oui", "Non sélectionné"), class = "factor"), 
    SP03_other = c(NA_character_, NA_character_)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")